# I am not getting "CSS rules to specify families" in google fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts, google-fonts

I am trying to get the font family CSS (on the google font website) which is used to define font family properties for the selected font applied to content.

Usually, you see a code block **"CSS rules to specify families"** under link/import tag code on right side of screen – but the expected css text is currently missing.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: This is indeed a **bug in the current google fonts UI**. If you open google fonts in firefox, you will see the CSS snippet as expected (or just as before). Otherwise just write your the font-family property value in quotes and specify the selected font weights like so: `    font-family: 'Open Sans'; font-weight:400`. To be honest, this is not the first time that Google Font's UI has changed for the worse ...

Answer (score 0):

In the "Selected Family" pane on right, you'll see a section with the code to embed in your HTML/ CSS files to import a font.

To use the  tag, add the HTML tag to the  section of your HTML file with the content to style.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap">
```

Else, you can use @import selector on top of your CSS file to import fonts using the Google Font URL.

```css
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');
</style>
```

Now in your CSS file, you can use the code under the section "CSS rules to specify families" as:

```css
/* Example CSS to apply the font family */
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

As you can see, you will be able to specify font-weights too if the desired weights are also imported in the URL as shown:

'https:// fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:**wght@400;700**&display=swap'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
font-family:'Black Ops One',sans-serif;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the code under the section "CSS rules to specify families" as:

> 

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans"> 
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

... hope this might be helpful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).